# how can I change the java code into c or c++ code for use it with Android JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to change this java code to c or c++,and use it on android JNI.
how can I do it?and how to use the java params map or java object

now I have the new question, I can create .h file，I can create .so library,and I can create easy .c code on java native function and invoke it successful。for example ：print an String “hello world！”； but how to change this java code to c or c++ code for android JNI, anyone can give me the c or c++ code ,had better to control+c and control+v to use it good! Thanks you very match!!!!

```
/**
 * 获取签名值
 *
 * @param secretKey
 * @param params
 *            请求参数
 * @return
 */
private static String getSign(String secretKey, Map<String, String[]> params) {

    String[] keys = params.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    Arrays.sort(keys);

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (!"sign".equals(key)) {
            String[] value = params.get(key);
            query.append(key);
            for (String string : value) {
                query.append(string);
            }
        }

    }
    return MD5(secretKey + query.toString());
}

public static String MD5(String str) {

    try {
        MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        m.reset();
        m.update(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
        String hashtext = bigInt.toString(16);

        while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
            hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
        }
        return hashtext;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("MD5 init failed.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you should convert it by hand.

- Read and understand Java code
- Write C or C++ code.

You are unlikely to find a tool that will translate Java code to C or C++ and produce efficient code; i.e. code that is comparable in performance to code you wrote yourself.  Since the point of using JNI is (I assume) to optimize performance ... a tool that gives your inefficient C / C++ is is pointless.

Comment: Sorry,My English is very poor.now I edit the question and add the details,can you see what it is?if you can and know how to do it,please tell me,thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

As the question is a kind of fuzzy, I can only give some coarse:

There are some approaches to convert java to c++ with tools like https://bitbucket.org/arnetheduck/j2c
But it might be a good idea just to clone your java-files and adapt them by hand. Booth languages are not that different and by doing so you ll retain control.

For JNI / NDK I dont know your skillevel, but you might want to take a look at https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/

For Lists, Maps, etc , just use the STL. Its reliable and works since the begin of the mankind (or so)

Comment: Sorry,My English is very poor.now I edit the question and add the details,can you see what it is?if you can and know how to do it,please tell me,thanks very much!!